# Restrict queries on top of partitioned tables to select partitions in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to figure out a way to prevent the users read all the partitions from a partitioned table by mistake. In Apache hive, the same can be accomplished using strict mode to ensure that queries select specific partitions or limit the results.

About strict mode in Hive.

> The mode in which the Hive operations are being performed. In strict
>   mode, some risky queries are not allowed to run. For example, full
>   table scans are prevented (see HIVE-10454) and ORDER BY requires a
>   LIMIT clause.

Any ideas how implement this without creating different tables for each partition nor views ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any ideas how implement this without creating different tables for each partition nor views

When creating your table set the option **Require partition filter** which will force the users to use partition filter when accessing the table

This is the checkbox in the webUI

[image]

or you can use DML command as described in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#table_option_list)

```
    #standardSQL
     CREATE TABLE mydataset.newtable
     (
       x INT64 OPTIONS(description="An optional INTEGER field")
     )
     PARTITION BY DATE(_PARTITIONTIME)
     OPTIONS(
       require_partition_filter = true
     )
```

Comment: it does the trick :). do you know how set this without the UI ? It looks like is not possible create column partition tables (only ingestion partitioned) from the UI. thanks!

Comment: I update my answer with what you have asked, Please consider accepting the answer and not only voting up. tnk :)